# How to select a class in multi-classes element and still keep the purpose of other classes?

Tags: jquery

I have two class, one for CSS style and others for use in jquery, but only one can be used for some reasons, so if I put this

```
$("<button class='command_button' class='pn'>Sleep</button>")
```

It will use the CSS style of .command_button but the function that use $(".pn").fadeOut(0); no longer work, yet if I switch those two classes around, the function now works but style wont work anymore leaving it a bland white button... How do I get those functions to use class but still leave other classes working as intended?

Comment: why not `$("<button class='command_button pn'>Sleep</button>")` ?

Comment: I was going to ask, but @PranavCBalan sort of beat me to it - why aren't you putting both classes in the same class="" attribute?

Comment: duplicate attribute is invalid

Comment: Thanks you guys so much, I was even aware that you can put more than one "selector" in the same class. but this fixes my problem and make it that much easier for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All classes should be in the same attribute, separated by spaces, like this:

`"<button class='command_button pn'>Sleep</button>"`

Then, your selector would be `$('button.pn.command_button')`

In terms of the functionality assigned to each class, you will have to provide more information (details, html/css/js ) to be able to tell more.